# Rewriting URL for the default action in controllers

Tags: grails, url-rewriting, url-mapping, grails-controller

I'm having trouble rewriting URL's in Grails:

I've got 2 controllers `BlogController` and `ProjectsController` each with a default `def index = { }` and matching view.

Now when I create the following links:

```
<g:link controller="blog">Blog</g:link>
<g:link controller="projects">Projects</g:link>
```

They get translated to `http://localhost:8080/myapp/blog/index` and `http://localhost:8080/myapp/projects/index`. But want them (and all other controllers default action) to be without the trailing `/index`.

Can anyone help me do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to specify *action* parameter in *link* tag as space.

```
<g:link controller="projects" action=" ">Projects</g:link>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [a Named URL Mapping](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#6.4.9%20Named%20URL%20Mappings)

Add this to your `grails-app/conf/UrlMappings.groovy`

```
    name blog: "/blog" {
            controller = "blog"
            action = "index"
    }
    name projects: "/projects" {
            controller = "projects"
            action = "index"
    }
```

and change your links to use the mapping parameter:

```
<g:link mapping="blog">Blog</g:link>
<g:link mapping="projects">Projects</g:link>
```

Comment: This works, but it doesn't really scale well. Every controller would need his own named mapping.

Comment: The named mappings are actually excessive. If you just provide a mapping for /blog to the proper controller/action, the link tag will remap it correctly. So, "/blog"(controller: "blog", action: "index") is all that is needed. The link tag w/ controller="blog" action="index" will map back to "/blog" correctly.